# web.config rewrite not applying negate attribute

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm trying to configure a web config to redirect all http traffic to https. But I don't want this to apply when in the dev environment (e.g localhost). The below code I have tried but it's still re-writing to https when on localhost.

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^127\.0\.0\.1(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: According to your rule, I have created a test demo on my side, it works well, It doesn't redirect localhost and local ip to https and redirect hostname URL to https.  I suggest you could try to follow the lex provided article to enable FRT to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks both, I'll retry @LexLi link this evening.